# Namespace must be defined to use Custom Metrics

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to deploy Memory metric which comes under guest metrics for a VM using Terraform, I have already defined namespace for the metric that I am using but its throwing below error.

Error creating or updating metric alert "Memory Usage Alert" (resource group "MyTemp"): insights.MetricAlertsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="The following metric name(s) were not found: Memory\% Committed bytes
in use. **Please note that for custom metrics, the relevant metric namespace must be specified.**

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "myalert" {
  name                      = "Memory Usage Alert"
  resource_group_name       = var.rg_name //resource name to which you want to deploy this alert
  scopes                    = [var.virtual_machine_id]
  description               = "Action will be triggered when Memory Utilzation count is greater than 85."
  target_resource_type      = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
  target_resource_location  = "centralindia"
  frequency                 = "PT30M"
  window_size               = "P1D"
  severity                  = "2"
  enabled                   = "true"

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics"
    metric_name      = "Memory\\% Committed bytes in use"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "GreaterThanOrEqual"
    threshold        = 85
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = var.action_name
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if you have sent these metrics to the azure monitor?

Comment: No, this is the main template and I have another variables file which is for storing virtual machine resource id

Comment: If you want to use the custom metric to create a metric alter, we should you send custom metric data to azure monitor at first

Comment: yeah, but don't know how to send custom metric to azure monitor using terraform, will be be great if you can help me here

Comment: Which type of vm you use?

Comment: Windows (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, you can refer to the following script

1. Send Azure guest VM metrics to Azure monitor with  Azure Diagnostics VM extension. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostics-extension-overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/collect-custom-metrics-guestos-resource-manager-vm)

```
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}
data  "azurerm_resource_group" "mygroup" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "account" {
  name                     = "myaccount1458975"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.mygroup.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.mygroup.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmextension" {
  name                       = random_string.password.result
  virtual_machine_id         = < your VM id>
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
  type                       = "IaaSDiagnostics"
  type_handler_version       = "1.11"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
   depends_on = [
      azurerm_storage_account.account
   
  ]
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
       "StorageAccount": "${azurerm_storage_account.account.name}",
          "WadCfg": {
            "SinksConfig": {
              "Sink": [
                {
                  "name": "AzMonSink",
                  "AzureMonitor": {}
                }
              ]
            },
            "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
              "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
              "Metrics": {
                "resourceId": "your VM id",
                "MetricAggregation": [
                  {
                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                  },
                  {
                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {
                "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error"
              },
              "PerformanceCounters": {
                "sinks": "AzMonSink",
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Privileged Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% User Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\Processor Frequency",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Processes",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Thread Count",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Handle Count",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\System Up Time",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Context Switches/sec",
                    "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Processor Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\% Committed Bytes In Use",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Available Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Committed Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Cache Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pool Paged Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pool Nonpaged Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pages/sec",
                    "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Page Faults/sec",
                    "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Working Set",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Working Set - Private",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Read Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Write Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Idle Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Bytes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Read Bytes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Write Bytes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Transfers/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Reads/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Writes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Read",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Write",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Free Space",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Free Megabytes",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Total/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Sent/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Received/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Sent/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Received/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Outbound Errors",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Received Errors",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "WindowsEventLog": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "DataSource": [
                  {
                    "name": "Application!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2 or Level = 3)]]"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Security!*[System[band(Keywords,4503599627370496)]]"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "System!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2 or Level = 3)]]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
    }
SETTINGS
 
  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "${azurerm_storage_account.account.name}",
          "storageAccountKey": "${azurerm_storage_account.account.primary_access_key }",
          "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
    }
SETTINGS

  
}
```

**Please note that before running the script, you need to enable Azure MSI and boot_diagnostics in your VM**

2. Create Metric Alert

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "myalert" {
  name                     = "myalert"
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name
  scopes                   = [var.virtual_machine_id]
  description              = "Action will be triggered when Memory Utilzation count is greater than 85."
  severity                 = "2"
  enabled                  = "true"
  frequency                = "PT1M"
  window_size              = "PT5M",
  target_resource_type     = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
  target_resource_location = "japaneast"

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics"
    metric_name       = "Memory\\% Committed bytes in use"
    aggregation       = "Average"
    operator          = "GreaterThanOrEqual"
    threshold         = 85

   
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = var.action_group_name
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Jim Xu, First script that is to send Guest OS Metrics to Monitor worked, I have enabled the boot_diagnostics on my VM but it is still throwing the same error. Seems to be for Central India Region this metric is not supported. I appreciate your answer Thanks.