# Enable guest level monitoring on Azure with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to enable guest level monitoring on a Azure VM with Terraform. I'm looking for the new way with Monitor Agent because I want to create alerts on disk space for Linux and Windows VM.
I follow this answer (2022) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72624929/21310522 but it doesn't allow me to retreive free disk space and add an alert on it.

With the portal it's quite simple, I enabled Insight ans quest level monitoring. But I'm stuck to understand which ressources I need in Terraform to do the same.

Someone already try this ?

Here is the snippet of my ressources :

```
locals {
  vm_suffix = "vmtest01"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-test" {
  name     = "${var.resource_prefix}-test"
  location = var.resource_group_location
  tags     = var.tags
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "net-test" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-net"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  address_space       = ["192.168.0.0/22"]
  tags                = var.tags
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "vm-subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.resource_prefix}-${local.vm_suffix}"
  address_prefixes     = ["192.168.0.0/24"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.net-test.name
}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-vm-subnet-association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.vm-subnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg-vm-subnet.id
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg-vm-subnet" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-${local.vm_suffix}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  security_rule {
    name                       = "Allow22InboundFromAll"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowRDPInboundFromAll"
    priority                   = 101
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-ip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                            = "${var.resource_prefix}-${local.vm_suffix}"
  location                        = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.vm-nic.id]
  size                            = "Standard_D1_v2"
  admin_username                  = "infra"
  admin_password                  = "REDACTED"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "OpenLogic"
    offer     = "CentOS"
    sku       = "7.5"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  os_disk {
    name                 = "${var.resource_prefix}-${local.vm_suffix}"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = "128"
  }
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.mi.id]
  }
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm-nic" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-${local.vm_suffix}"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.resource_prefix}-${local.vm_suffix}-ipcfg"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.vm-subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id
  }
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = "${var.resource_prefix}sa"
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "mi" {
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  name                     = "${var.resource_prefix}-monitor-mi"
  tags                     = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "mi-ra" {
  scope                = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  role_definition_name = "Virtual Machine Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.mi.principal_id
  depends_on           = [
    azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspace" {
  name                = "law01"
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent" {        
  name                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"

  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
}


 resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "example" {
  name                = "example-rules"
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.location
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace.id
      name                  = "test-destination-log"
    }

    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "test-destination-metrics"
    }
  } 

  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
    destinations = ["test-destination-log"]
  }

  data_sources {
    performance_counter {
      streams                       = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      counter_specifiers            = ["\\VmInsights\\DetailedMetrics"]
      name                          = "VMInsightsPerfCounters"
    }
}
 }

# associate to a Data Collection Rule
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule_association" "example1" {
  name                    = "example1-dcra"
  target_resource_id      = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  data_collection_rule_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.example.id
  description             = "example"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "action-group" {
  name                = "${var.resource_prefix}-ag"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-test.name
  short_name          = "${var.resource_prefix}-ag"

  email_receiver {
    name          = "email"
    email_address = "REDACTED"
  }
  webhook_receiver {
    name                    = "${var.resource_prefix}-webhook"
    service_uri             = "REDACTED"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "main" {
    name                     = "test-alert"
    frequency                = "PT1M"
    window_size              = "PT1M"
    resource_group_name      = "test"
    scopes                   = [
        azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
    ]
    severity                 = 3
    tags                     = var.tags
    target_resource_location = "francecentral"
    target_resource_type     = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"

    action {
        action_group_id    = azurerm_monitor_action_group.action-group.id
        webhook_properties = {}
    }

    criteria {
        aggregation            = "Average"
        metric_name            = "LogicalDisk\\% Free Space"
        metric_namespace       = "azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics"
        operator               = "LessThan"
        skip_metric_validation = false
        threshold              = 5
    }

    auto_mitigate            = true
    enabled                  = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code which should work:

Make sure the monitor metric name and parameters are correct.

Note: ***Prior to running the script, enable Azure MSI and boot_diagnostics in your VM.***

main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "net-test" {
  name                = "kavya-net"
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["192.168.0.0/22"]
  
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "vm-subnet" {
  name                 = "kavya-subnet"
  address_prefixes     = ["192.168.0.0/24"]
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.net-test.name
}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-vm-subnet-association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.vm-subnet.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg-vm-subnet.id
}
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg-vm-subnet" {
  name                = "ntwrksg"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  security_rule {
    name                       = "Allow22InboundFromAll"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  security_rule {
    name                       = "AllowRDPInboundFromAll"
    priority                   = 101
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "3389"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
  tags = var.tags
}



resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
 name                = "kavyantwrkip"
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes      = 30

  
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "mi" {
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  name                     = "ka-monitor-mi"
  tags                     = var.tags
}


resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                            = "linucvmkav"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.vm-nic.id]
  size                            = "Standard_D1_v2"
  admin_username                  = "infra"
  admin_password                  = "Kavya@123"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "OpenLogic"
    offer     = "CentOS"
    sku       = "7.5"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  os_disk {
    name                 = "myosdisk"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb         = "128"
  }
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
   identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.mi.id]
  }
  

}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm-nic" {
  name                = "nitn-nic"
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vm-nic-ipcfg"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.vm-subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.id
  }
 
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa" {
  name                     = "kavysact"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
   location =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

}



resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "mi-ra" {
  scope                = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  role_definition_name = "Virtual Machine Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.mi.principal_id
  depends_on           = [
    azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm, azurerm_user_assigned_identity.mi
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspace" {
  name                = "law01kav"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent" {        
  name                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                       = "AzureMonitorLinuxAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = "true"

  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
}


 resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "example" {
  name                = "exampleka-rules"
 location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  destinations {
    log_analytics {
      workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspace.id
      name                  = "test-destination-log"
    }

    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "test-destination-metrics"
    }
  } 

  data_flow {
    streams      = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
    destinations = ["test-destination-log"]
  }

  data_sources {
    performance_counter {
      streams                       = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"]
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      counter_specifiers            = ["\\VmInsights\\DetailedMetrics"]
      name                          = "VMInsightsPerfCounters"
    }
}
 }

# associate to a Data Collection Rule
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule_association" "example1" {
  name                    = "example1k-dcra"
  target_resource_id      = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
  data_collection_rule_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.example.id
  description             = "example"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "action-group" {
  name                = "kavya-ag"
resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "kavyaag"

  email_receiver {
    name          = "email"
    email_address = "kavyasaraboju@gmail.com"
  }
 
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "main" {
    name                     = "testmtalert"
    frequency                = "PT1M"
    window_size              = "PT1M"
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    scopes                   = [
        azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.id
    ]
    severity                 = 3
    //tags                     = var.tags
    target_resource_location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location  //"francecentral"
    target_resource_type     = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"

    action {
        action_group_id    = azurerm_monitor_action_group.action-group.id
        webhook_properties = {}
    }

    criteria {
        aggregation            = "Average"
        metric_name            = "LogicalDisk % Free Space"
        metric_namespace       = "azure.vm.windows.guestmetrics"
        operator               = "LessThan"
        skip_metric_validation = false
        threshold              = 5
    }

    auto_mitigate            = true
    enabled                  = true
}


And   send guest metrics to diagnostics extensions.
```

> Azure Diagnostics extension is an agent in Azure Monitor that collects
> monitoring data from the guest operating system of Azure compute
> resources including virtual machines.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vmextension" {
  name                       = random_string.password.result
  virtual_machine_id         = < your VM id>
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
  type                       = "IaaSDiagnostics"
  type_handler_version       = "1.11"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
   depends_on = [
      azurerm_storage_account.account
   
  ]
  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
       "StorageAccount": "${azurerm_storage_account.account.name}",
          "WadCfg": {
            "SinksConfig": {
              "Sink": [
                {
                  "name": "AzMonSink",
                  "AzureMonitor": {}
                }
              ]
            },
            "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
              "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
              "Metrics": {
                "resourceId": "your VM id",
                "MetricAggregation": [
                  {
                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
                  },
                  {
                    "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {
                "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error"
              },
              "PerformanceCounters": {
                "sinks": "AzMonSink",
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Processor Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% Privileged Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\% User Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Processor Information(_Total)\\Processor Frequency",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Processes",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Thread Count",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Handle Count",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\System Up Time",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Context Switches/sec",
                    "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\System\\Processor Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\% Committed Bytes In Use",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Available Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Committed Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Cache Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pool Paged Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pool Nonpaged Bytes",
                    "unit": "Bytes",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Pages/sec",
                    "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Memory\\Page Faults/sec",
                    "unit": "CountPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Working Set",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Process(_Total)\\Working Set - Private",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Read Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Disk Write Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Idle Time",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Bytes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Read Bytes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Write Bytes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Transfers/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Reads/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Disk Writes/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Transfer",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Read",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk sec/Write",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Read Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Avg. Disk Write Queue Length",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\% Free Space",
                    "unit": "Percent",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\LogicalDisk(_Total)\\Free Megabytes",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Total/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Sent/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Bytes Received/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Sent/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Received/sec",
                    "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Outbound Errors",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  },
                  {
                    "counterSpecifier": "\\Network Interface(*)\\Packets Received Errors",
                    "unit": "Count",
                    "sampleRate": "PT60S"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "WindowsEventLog": {
                "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
                "DataSource": [
                  {
                    "name": "Application!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2 or Level = 3)]]"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "Security!*[System[band(Keywords,4503599627370496)]]"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "System!*[System[(Level = 1 or Level = 2 or Level = 3)]]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
    }
SETTINGS
 
  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "${azurerm_storage_account.account.name}",
          "storageAccountKey": "${azurerm_storage_account.account.primary_access_key }",
          "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net/"
    }
SETTINGS

  
}
```

[image]

Check this reference
[azure - Namespace must be defined to use Custom Metrics - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196909/namespace-must-be-defined-to-use-custom-metrics/64272961#64272961) by @Jim Xu